# How to get paid for design work?

Tags: client-relations, designers

What is the best way to receive payment for one off design work?

I have been asked to do some design work for a company logo for my family friend's big business. It is my first proper design work which involves designing for someone outside friends and family.

I was wondering what payment method would be best to use in the UK and won't look completely unprofessional? Should I create a personal paypal and receive payment through that or is it ok to just send bank details and ask them to pay into my account?

I would like to tell them my preferred payment methods alongside my design mockup files so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's an awfully broad question. I'd advice you to search the [client-relation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-relations) tag and questions with 'pricing' on this site. And: **first** have a contract, and **only then** start making mockups!

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't give out bank account information.

Take cash, Square, PayPal or check. If using cash then invest in a receipt book with carbon copy that both you and the customer can sign and date for proof of purchase.

Regarding the bank account info -- this may be different outside the US but I still wouldn't do it. There's just no reason in my opinion to give out bank account information when there's other options available.

Comment: Thsi is highly dependent on where you are. Direct billing to bank account with electronic invoicing is normal in some parts of the world.

Comment: @joojaa probably true. Edited to clarify that.

Comment: ACH payments are also common in the US (where the client has your account info and direct deposits). They don't really have any more information than someone looking at a check of yours would have (Account and routing #s). But yes, it is your banking info. I'm always hesitant to provide ACH info because it's just *another* database somewhere that can be hacked with my information in it. Has little to do with the client directly. Frankly I do check, Paypal or Square.. if the client can't do that.. they aren't legitimate.

Comment: Maybe it's different elsewhere, but it's very normal in the UK to take payments by direct bank transfer (i.e. giving your bank details). This is how I take 99% of payments, and how I pay most most invoices to both individuals and large companies. Cheques used to be common but they're rare these days (a lot of banks won't even give out cheque books anymore)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to accept payment in as many ways possible. It will make it easier for you to get paid by the companies you work for.

For example, I had a client that could pay me as soon as I billed them, if I accept credit card payments. Or I could wait 1-2 months for them to submit the bill to their corporate office and then wait for them to mail the cheque out.

Other clients like to pay via direct deposit to a bank account. Others (most) by cheque. More and more accounting departments are starting to incorporate online payments into their methods of approved payment, which is great for everyone in my opinion.

Bottom line, make it easy for the client to pay you. The more painless you can make the process, the more likely you are to get paid quicker. And especially important when working for smaller businesses/clients, make sure you get paid. Cash flow can be painful for small business, and the quicker you get paid the better.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Paypal many times before for one off and even repeat jobs to get payments from the EU or US, nobody really said anything about this being unprofessional.

Larger clients however will probably rather pay to a bank account.